# Wordpress Super Admin menu not enabled

Tags: buddypress, multisite

Hi I am trying to create a social network using buddypress.I found a book that has detail instructions on how to create a number of wordpress sites : [wordpress blueprints](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1847199364)

Just to be clear I have wordpress installed on localhost in e-commerce folder.The first stept that I done was to add this code in wp-config.php:

```
<?php
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
?>
```

This enabled the instalation menu.After I clicked install I was asked to create a folder in wp-content named blogs.dir.

I was give this code to put in 
wp-config.php:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
$base = '/e-commerce/';
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/e-commerce/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

and this code to put in wordpress .htaccess file and replace what is there:

```
  RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /e-commerce/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Next I was asked to relog and after relog a Super Admin menu should have appeared in the dashboard but the menu is not appearing for me.

What is the problem and how can I conrect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of WordPress have gotten rid of the "Super Admin" menu on the left-hand dashboard menu in favor of a "Network Admin" section.

It sounds like you installed multisite just fine, so under the "My Sites" option in the top toolbar, you'll now see a link to the Network Admin section.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Step_5:_Network_Admin_Settings